# Log4J: unable to delete old files with IfFileName and properties

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

We use log4j in version 2.17.2 in our application.
We use properties to configure log4j. But following configuration do not delete old logs.

(${...} is a replacement for the real path)

```
appender.solrAppender.type = RollingFile
appender.solrAppender.name = SOLRFile
appender.solrAppender.fileName = ${...}/solr/solr.log
appender.solrAppender.filePattern = ${...}/solr/solr-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.zip

appender.solrAppender.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.solrAppender.layout.pattern = %d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n

appender.solrAppender.policies.type = Policies
appender.solrAppender.policies.trigger.type=TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy

appender.solrAppender.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy

appender.solrAppender.strategy.deleteAction.type=Delete
appender.solrAppender.strategy.deleteAction.basePath=${...}/solr/
appender.solrAppender.strategy.deleteAction.maxDepth=2
appender.solrAppender.strategy.deleteAction.testMode=false
appender.solrAppender.strategy.deleteAction.followLinks=false
appender.solrAppender.strategy.deleteAction.fileName.type=IfFileName
appender.solrAppender.strategy.deleteAction.fileName.glob=*/solr-*.log.zip
appender.solrAppender.strategy.deleteAction.fileCount.type=IfAccumulatedFileCount
appender.solrAppender.strategy.deleteAction.fileCount.age=2
```

No files are deleted. I checked the other examples here, but I didn't find a running configuration for me.

```
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx xxx 1209 Feb  8 00:00 solr-20230207.log.zip
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx xxx 1184 Feb  9 00:00 solr-20230208.log.zip
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx xxx 18118 Feb 10 00:00 solr-20230209.log.zip
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx xxx 2438 Feb 11 00:01 solr-20230210.log.zip
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx xxx 1184 Feb 12 00:01 solr-20230211.log.zip
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx xxx 1192 Feb 13 00:01 solr-20230212.log.zip
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx xxx 1184 Feb 14 00:01 solr-20230213.log.zip
-rw-rw-r--. 1 xxx xxx 14000 Feb 14 09:16 solr.log
```